# Requesting Resources Until Exhaustion

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, callback, http

When an API has a 'next' feature, I use the following pattern to obtain all the results:

```
/** Obtains a list of channels followed by a user */
function get_follows(username, callback) {
    var channels = [];
    function handler(data) {
        if (!data || data.follows.length == 0) {
            callback(channels);
            return;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < data.follows.length; i++)
            channels.push(data.follows[i].channel);
        JSON.load(data._links.next, handler);
    }
    var url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/"+username+"/follows/channels?limit=75&offset=0&on_site=1";
    JSON.load(url, handler);
}
```

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like your code, and would use it myself, some thoughts:

- I assume you declare `url` next to `JSON.load` because you want to declare it close to where you use it. I would still recommend using 1 comma separated list of variables on the top.
- lowerCamelCase is good for you, `get_follows` -> `getFollows` -> `getFollowedChannels` ?
- Comparing to `0` should be done with `===`, if you do it for the length of an array I would go with a falsey comparison: `if (!data || !data.follows.length) {`

From a design perspective, you are circumventing the paging system, are you sure you always need every single channel? I hope you at least cache the retrieved information.